# WinRM from Linux using domain account without kerberos?

Tags: python, ubuntu, kerberos, winrm

Researching this subject has led to a maddening labyrinth of partial answers, misdirection and rabbit holes.  I can't believe with millions of Linux and Windows servers out there that a simple answer doesn't exist.  So, let's make the world a better place!

My desire is simple:

To authenticate with WinRM, *from Ubuntu*, using a domain account and password.  My requirements dictate the account/password **are unknown to me at setup** (only at runtime), therefore can't be 'hardcoded' into a ticket, certificate, etc.

My code is in Python and I'm currently using `pywinrm`, which doesn't seem to support this either.  I've only ever been able to get a domain login to work by setting up Kerberos on Ubuntu, which is nearly impossible in itself, and doesn't seem to meet my goal of dynamic credentials unless I'm missing something.

Much respect to anyone who can either a) explain why this is an impossible goal or b) give some concrete direction on accomplishing it.  I'm not a Windows expert, so verbose answers are most helpful.  (If this actually is possible with Kerberos, please clarify my misunderstanding.)

To demonstrate I've done my homework (even though these items may be incorrect), here's what I currently believe to be true:

- WinRM supports several auth methods, including: basic, kerberos, digest, negotiate(ntlm), certificate and credssp.
- "basic" *does not appear* to support a domain account, ex: DOMAIN//bob
- it appears you can't explicitly request NTLM - negotiate seems to the only way to access NTLM, which should allow domain accounts
- digest looked promising at first, until I read numerous references to it actually not being supported after all, even though it's mentioned.
- it's entirely unclear to me if the certificate or credssp options actually meet my needs, if they even provide a way to auth with the domain at all